# Wi-fi not browsing after using VPN

Tags: wireless, internet, vpn

I connected a vpn (wi-free) so i could access some website using a different ip address, but on disconnecting to use my wireless connection back, it only connects and does not browse the internet until i connect with the vpn.

I have uninstalled the vpn but the issue still occurs. I had to install it back so i can browse the internet.

Please does anyone know how i can get internet access back with just my wireless?

Answer (score 0):

Your VPN-CLient might set the default route to the VPN-connection.

In Windows you can address this issue by unchecking "Use remote network as default gateway" in "Advanced Settings for IPv4" and in Linux the following command will add the default gateway:

```
sudo route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ethx
```

You'll have to exchange the x's with the appropriate numbers, the IP of your router and the NIC you use for internet so maybe eth0.

Hope it could help.